# Assigning one structure type into another type in c++

Tags: c++, object, memory, structure

We know that we can assign only one structure object to another having same type but why can't we assign one structure object of type A to another structure object of type B?

Here,

```
struct typeA{
    int inA1; 
    int inA2;
};

struct typeB{
    int inB1;
    int inB2;
};

int main(){
    typeA varA;
    typeB varB;
    varA = varB//Here it will show compile time error. Why it can't 
               //assign object of typeB to object of typeA since both have
               //same type of members
    return 0;
}
```

**Why we can't assign object of typeB structure to object of typeA structure since both have same type of members?**

**Why it is made a rule to not assign the different type of structure object to another since they may have same members?**

Comment: "*Why it is made a rule to not assign the different type of structure object to another since they may have same members?*" You assume that this behavior would be the default, that there has to be a rule to *stop* it from working. In reality, there would have to be a rule *allowing* it to work. Different types are *different*, even if you think they're the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will generate an assignment operator to assign a variable of the same type. However, even when both type have the same layout, it won't generate an assignment operator for it. It is also completely understandable, since it would be an easy source of error.

Why would it be a source of error?

Well, imagine if `typeB` would be defined like that:

```
struct typeB{
    int inB2; 
    int inB1;
};
```

Quite puzzling heh? Even though `typeA` and type `typeB` would have the same layout, you'd expect `inA1` to take the value of `inB1`, but the contrary would occur, and `inA1` would take the value of `inB2`.

Since the names don't affect the layout, and compilers don't knows you intentions about how that assignment should do, it won't assume anything and will not create a wrongly written assignment operator.

---

As such, that assignment operator you expected to exist is not generated by default, but you can write one for sure:

```
struct typeA{
    int inA1; 
    int inA2;

    typeA& operator=(const typeB& rhs) {
        inA1 = rhs.inB1;
        inA2 = rhs.inB2;

        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now the compiler knows how to assign them in the way you intended.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign unlike types to each other as a means of safety. While the underlying types are literally compatible, the compiler does not know the semantics - you may have accidentally assigned, say, someone's age and weight into their blood pressure measurements.

If you're really sure you want to do this, you can cast varB to typeA:

```
varA = (typeA)varB;
```

This instructs the compiler that you're very sure of what you want to do, though in some cases, the compiler may elect to warn you still if it detects that you may lose some of the information being carried, but it also may not.

Comment: Since this question is about C++, would you care changing the cast to a `reinterpret_cast` and warn OP about it's potential pitfalls? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer what you are looking for but if you don't want explicit constructor .You can let **Implicit constructor** handle this situation
**varA = varB;**

```
#include <iostream>

struct typeA{
    int inA1;
    int inA2;
};

struct typeB : typeA
    {
        int inB1;
        int inB2;
        // implicit default ctor typeB::typeBB()
        // implicit copy ctor typeB::typeB(const B&)
};


int main(){
    typeA varA;
    typeB varB;
    varA = varB;//handled by implicit constructor 
    return 0;
}
```